# How to create a Quick Action in macOS to Resize/Scale an image?

Tags: automator

Currently I use a 3rd party MacOS App to open and "resize/scale" by 50% any imported picture from my iPhone.  This makes it a bit more manageable but it's tedious.

Is there a shell script that can be used in Automator to create a {Quick Action} so it can be used in Finder by right-clicking on one or more images and having a "Resize Image 50%" quick action?

I'm running Catalina 10.15.7.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you searched for such a script or considered recording one?

Comment: ...yeah, it’s built into Automator! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was "built-in" all along but I missed it.  Thanks @wowfunhappy for pointing it out.  I am including a screenshot of it for reference. Note this version overrides the original file. If a copy is desired, uncheck the "Replace Existing Files" checkbox.

[image]